# How to replace sem_init() with sem_open() for non pointer semaphore?

Tags: ios, c, semaphore

I currently stuck in a problem.

Below is the original code

```
sem_t s;
sem_init(&s, 0, 1);
```

And I need to replace sem_init with sem_open because it will be used on iOS

```
sem_t s;
sem_open("/s", O_CREAT, 0644, 1); //which will return sem_t*
```

How should I assign the return address to s?
Thanks

p.s. i do not declare sem_t* s, because this is a huge library which I won't change it too much

Comment: Isn't addresses can only be stored to pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new semaphore pointer,

```
 sem_t *sptr;
```

Invoke `sem_open` as `sptr` holds the address,

```
 sptr = sem_open("/s", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
```

And below preprocessor macro should do the trick,

```
 #define s *sptr
```

With the above method, when ever `s` is passed as argument, for example `sem_wait(&s)` boils to `sem_wait(&*sptr) => sem_wait(sptr)` which is desired without changing `sem_t s`.

Comment: Thanks, but in some code it is used as a instance member like
"sem_wait(&(myInstance->s))", and the instance may be different name

How to define the macro?